# Count number of matches from a list words in a string

Tags: c#

I have a list of words

```
var words = List<string> { "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry" };'
```

and a string

```
var fruitString = "Apple Orange Banana Plum";
```

I know if I do

```
var hasFruits = words.Contains(w => fruitString.Contains(w));
```

that I can tell if the string contains any of those words. What I need to do is tell how many of those words match.

I know that I can do

```
var count = 0;
foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (fruitString.Contains(word))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

but is there a way of doing this in a Linq one-liner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check *count* of words which appear in string separated by whitespaces, you can use intersection of sets:

```
fruitString.Split().Intersect(words).Count() // 2
```

If you want to check *which* words your string have - just remove Count call:

```
fruitString.Split().Intersect(words) // "Apple", "Banana"
```

---

Note1: if you do `String.Contains` then `"Apple"` will be found in `"Applejack"` string

Note2: passing `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` as second argument to `Intersect` method call will make ignore case string comparison and "apple" will match "Apple".

Note3: you can use `Regex.Split` to get words from string which has not only white spaces between words. E.g. for something like `"I look to the east and see: apple, orange and banana!"`

Comment: I've accepted your answers as it answer the question I posed. But Jame Thorpe's answer is closer to the problem that I'm actually trying to solve. My thanks to you both.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, simply swap `Contains` for [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var count = words.Count(w => fruitString.Contains(w));
```

Note that this retains the same result as your original code - as pointed out in [Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42350671/791010), this approach may be naive, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had as my first attempt. What I hadn't realised that the .Contains is case sensitive when performed against a list. My original piece of code:

words.Contains(w => fruitString.Contains(w));

was part of an part of an EntityFrameWork where clause which defaulted to case-insensitive match - hence my confusion.